# Why I see "question eligible for bounty since 1 hour ago" and not "start bounty" button

Tags: support, user-interface, bounty

I had asked this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231808/14414) 2 days back, and now I see at the bottom, the link " 
question eligible for bounty since 1 hour ago", and if I click on it, it takes me to the bounty information page. I don't see the "start bounty" button on this question. I have bounty previleges and I see the "start bounty" button on some of my other questions. I have not started any bounty till now on this question. How can I start a bounty on this question.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page?

Comment: @quid : Have been doing that for the past half hour hoping that it is going through some extra period befor bounty being enabled.

Comment: @quid : do you see the "start bounty" button on your end?

Comment: Yes, looks normal to me.

Comment: @quid : If I may dare ask, could you please offer a bounty of 50 points on this question, if you feel its a worth question?

Comment: I did not read the question, and thus have no opinion on it either way.

Comment: @quid : BTW, I have also wrote an answer for it, and feel its almost correct, could you take a look at it? Its not that complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in this.

Comment: Now I am able to get "start bounty", but when I asked this question my rep was 91, and I needed minimum of 100 points to offer as I have my own answer written on that question.

Comment: Ah, I did not think of that restriction. Maybe write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Now I am able to get "start bounty", but when I asked this question my rep was 91, and I needed minimum of 100 points to offer as I have my own answer written on that question. This feature is mentioned as "avoid excessive self promotion via bounty"