# Why I cannot start bounty on my own question, just because I have answered it?

Tags: support, bounty

Can it circumvent and avoid awarding bounty for own answers and reward answers by posters other than the author of the question. Why avoid the author from starting bounty itself all together. In such case, won't the author be eligible to start bounty to draw attention, while having no interested to gain bounty which was offered by himself. this rule looks a bit redundant and avoidable.

I had answered it just to show progress and no intention of gaining points.

[Question :](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332439/14414)

Comment: I have retagged the question with ([meta-tag:support]) since it seems to be asking basically how bounties on the self-answered questions work. However, if you feel that the tag is relevant there, feel free to put the ([meta-tag:discussion]) tag back.

Comment: need some cash for bounty! That is the conclusion.

Comment: I don't mean real cash. I mean if I could get a couple of upvotes, I have enough points to start a bounty. by cash I mean points (rep)
I just used cash as funny alternative name for rep points. I myself am a poor man!

Answer (score 3):

You can find links to some basic information about bounties in the [corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/bounty/info).

These two points from the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) item [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) are relevant:

> You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount.

and

> If you have already answered the question before, the minimum bounty offer is 100.

So you cannot offer a bounty simply because your reputation (at the moment) is lower than minimum possible bounty amount. Once you gain enough reputation, you should be able to offer bounty for this question.

It seems that this feature was implemented in 2011, see: [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64824#64826) and 2011-09-20 entry in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#59446).

I will mention that deleting your answers will not help in this regard: [Why can't I add a bounty worth 50 reputation after deleting my answer on a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285048).

Comment: However, I see from your previous posts on meta that you are aware that the minimum bounty amount is 100 reputation points in such situations: [Why I see “question eligible for bounty since 1 hour ago” and not “start bounty” button](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2760#2761). So it's possible that I have misunderstood what you're asking about.

Comment: Oops, that was 3 years back. I should have seen it should have remembered. This is same as that question.